# Azure ML Pipeline: Specify input-path on compute

Tags: azureml-python-sdk

I got a python script which shall be executed as an Azure ML pipeline step. This script expects to find several file-sets in a certain tree structure e.g.

```
data/
├─ project_A/
│  ├─ data.csv
│  ├─ config.toml
├─ project_B/
│  ├─ data.csv
│  ├─ config.toml
├─ project_.../
│  ├─ ...
```

The script receives the base-path e.g. `./data/` as command line argument and walks the sub-directories.
Each file-set e.g. `project_A` is made available as a `URI_FOLDER` Azure ML Data Asset.
The Azure ML Python sdk v2 is used and the definition of the component looks like this:

```py
prep = command(
    name="preprocessing",
    code="./src/preprocessing.py",
    # actual paths passed at pipeline level
    inputs=dict(
        project_A=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT),  
        project_B=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT), 
        project_...),
    command="python preprocessing.py <base_dir>",
)
```

I would like to know how ensure a certain tree structure on the compute such that I can pass the `<base_dir>` to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you give in `inputs`, it is passed to command line arguments in the Python file. Here is the sample:

```py
command_job = command(
    code="./src",
    command="python main.py --iris-csv ${{inputs.iris_csv}} --learning-rate ${{inputs.learning_rate}} --boosting ${{inputs.boosting}}",
    environment="AzureML-lightgbm-3.2-ubuntu18.04-py37-cpu@latest",
    inputs={
        "iris_csv": Input(
            type="uri_file",
            path="https://azuremlexamples.blob.core.windows.net/datasets/iris.csv",
        ),
        "learning_rate": 0.9,
        "boosting": "gbdt",
    },
    compute="cpu-cluster",
)
```

If you observe `iris_csv`, `learning_rate`, and `boosting`, they are given in the inputs parameter, which is further passed to Python command arguments as `${{inputs.iris_csv}}`, `${{inputs.learning_rate}}`, and `${{inputs.boosting}}`. It's not like passing arguments in the command and using them in the `inputs` parameter.

In your case, if you are passing only `base_path`, give it in the `inputs` parameter as `uri_folder` and pass it to the command. Then take a path to `project_A`, `project_B`, etc., inside your Python file like below:

`project_A_path = os.path.join(<base_path>,'project_A')` and `project_B_path = os.path.join(<base_path>,'project_B')`

Command definition:

```py
prep = command(
    name="preprocessing",
    code="./src/preprocessing.py",
    # actual paths passed at pipeline level
    inputs=dict(
        base_path=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT)
        ),
    command="python preprocessing.py --base-path ${{inputs.base_path}}",
)
```

Or if there are only a few project folders, you can pass the project folder directly along with the base path as well:

```py
prep = command(
    name="preprocessing",
    code="./src/preprocessing.py",
    # actual paths passed at pipeline level
    inputs=dict(
        base_path=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT),
        project_A=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT),  
        project_B=Input(type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER, mode=InputOutputModes.RO_MOUNT), 
        project_...),
    command="python preprocessing.py --base-path ${{inputs.base_path}} --project_a_path ${{inputs.project_A}} --project_b_path ${{inputs.project_B}}",
)
```

I would still recommend you use only the base path in command arguments and construct the required project path inside the Python file.

Refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/tutorials/azureml-in-a-day/azureml-in-a-day.ipynb) notebook for more about the command job.